# Understanding insertion in linked list in C - pointers a

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

Indeed, I have found a lot of questions **similar** to mine, but none of them seems to be as silly as my obstacle to understand the basis of the insertion in a linked list in C.

```
typedef struct LList {
int value;
struct LList *next_list_id;
} LList;z
```

Given example code for insertion after a specified element (code from my lecture):

```
void insert_after(LList *orig, int element) {
LList *help;
help = (LList*)malloc(sizeof(LList));
help->next_list_id = orig->next_list_id;
help->value = element;
orig->next_list_id = help;
}
```

What I do not understand is something like:

```
help->next_list_id
```

In my understanding, `help` is a pointer to a structure, not a structure itself. **How can we use `->` operator for a pointer, if it is a pointer to a structure, not a structure?**

Comment: `A->B` means `(*A).B`.

Comment: ...because that is the function of that operator?

Comment: I think that MikeCAT answered my problem :) I have forgotten about that, thanks!